# Alinear verticalmente con bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo como una tarjeta de 700px * 750px y tengo una serie de elementos aparte del nav,
me gustaria alinearlos de forma vertical, que cada fila esté en una posición conforme a la altura de la tarjeta, de forma horizontal lo tengo ya como quiero, y de forma responsive, de forma horizontal uso el tamaño de col-md y col-sm pero para alinear verticalmente, solo veo la forma de position de bootstrap, pero no queda de forma responsive, al menos de la forma que sé

```css
.content {
  left:50%;
  padding:10vmin;
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.tarjeta {
  min-height: 750px;
  max-width: 700px;
}
  color:#ffc107;
 }


  ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <div
      class="m-0 vh-100 row justify-content-center align-items-center text-center"
    >
      <div
        class="container text-center tarjeta  col-sm-8 shadow-lg bg-info bg-opacity-75 rounded-4 border border-4 border-warning"
      >
        <ul
          class="mt-2 nav justify-content-center bg-info shadow bg-gradientmt-2 rounded-4 border border-2 border-white"
        >
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link active link-warning text-white"
              aria-current="page"
              href="#"
              >Inicio</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link link-warning text-white" href="skills.html"
              >Skills</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white" href="#"
              >Portafolio</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white">Redes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="pt-2 form-check form-switch form-check-reverse">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                id="flexSwitchCheckReverse"
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label text-black"
                for="flexSwitchCheckReverse"
                >Modo oscuro</label
              >
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="row align-items-center mt-5 ">
          <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-3 pb-3   ">
              <img class="text-center img-fluid  rounded-4 border border-4  border-success shadow-lg "
                  src="assets/img/perfil.JPG" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6  pb-3 ">
              <img class="text-center img-fluid  " id="logo" src="assets/img/pc-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-3  pb-3">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Portafolio</button>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row mt-4">
          <div class="col-sm-12 ">
              <p>blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla  
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-4 mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2  offset-md-4 mt-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
              <a class="nav-link link-warning text-white" href="#">LinkedIn</a>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 mt-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
              <a class="nav-link link-warning text-white" href="#">GitHub</a>
            </button>
          </div>
      </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

aquí muestro una foto de como me gustaría que estuviera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero por ejemplo si la primera fila la querría poner por ejemplo a 2/3 del alto como sería?

[image: esta sería en responsi]
no quedaría hueco por arriba

Comment: No hacía falta que crees una pregunta nueva, sino simplemente editar la anterior. Por cierto: alinear*.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, de todas maneras te recomiendo que para la disposición general de su página uses "css grid".

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer? Donde está el problema? Por favor explícanos más detalladamente tu problema

Comment: el primer row, me gustaría ponerlo justo en la mitad del tamaño de la tarjeta y que luego en movil se pongan uno encima del tro, despues el texto <p> justo debajo y centrado horizontalmente, se puede hacer con un col-sm-12, luego con los botones de redes sociales pegados abajo de la tarjeta

Comment: Es el código completo del `<body>`?

Comment: Faltaría unas clases que van antes de estas para dar un fondo dinámico

Comment: acabo de añadir una foto que muestra como me gustaría que qeudase en responsive, pero es que no logro por  la  primera fila, en el medio en pantalla completa, y luego en movil que esté acoplado arriba. y luego la descripción es fácil ponerlo siguiente a esta, pero las dos botoneras  no me deja ponerlo al final, a no ser que haga un position relative y absolute, pero eso luego para responsive no valen de nada